Node.js file upload with busboy, process file stream later
I have a very simple endpoint for file uploading with express and busboy. First I want to run a process with the text fields and only if that succeeds then upload the files to another system. First I'm waiting for the form data to be parsed and the files to be stored on the disk, I'm running the process with the text fields as parameters and then uploading the files and doing cleanup.
The question is, can I avoid storing the files on the disk first and instead stream/upload them directly into the other system, but only after waiting for the process to run?
import express from "express";
import busboy from "busboy";
import path from "node:path";
import fs from "node:fs";
import { pipeline } from "node:stream/promises";
const app = express();

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    const promises = [];
    const fields = {};

    bb.on("file", (fieldname, file, info) => {
      const { filename } = info;
      const saveTo = path.join(process.cwd(), filename);
      const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(saveTo);

      promises.push(pipeline(file, writeStream).then(() => saveTo));
    });

    bb.on("error", (error) => {
      reject(new Error(error.message));
    });

    bb.on("finish", async () => {
      const files = await Promise.all(promises);

      resolve({
        fields,
        files,
      });
    });

    bb.on("field", (name, value, test) => {
      fields[name] = value;
    });

    req.pipe(bb);
  });

  /*
  const successful = await runProcess(data.fields);

  if (successful) {
    await uploadFilesToOtherSystem(data.files);
  }

  await cleanUpFiles(data.files);
  */

  res.status(204).send();
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening...");
});



could you share the code inside the uploadFiles so we can get an idea how to implement via streams

The files would be uploaded to aws s3 and the upload function does a multipart upload so it can take the unknown size read stream as input. I can of course upload there directly but I want to runProcess first, so I would need to somehow store for later or pause the incoming file stream.
